# What's the XP cost to learn an unknown 1-dot art in a known arcanoi?

Tags: world-of-darkness, experience-points, wraith-the-oblivion

The 20th Anniversary edition of Wraith: the Oblivion describes the mechanic for learning unknown arts at the same rating as a known art (e.g. learning an initiate art, when the common art is known) thusly:

> An eligible character who already knows a common art for a given Arcanos rating may also learn the initiate art for the same rating or vice versa. This carries the same experience-point cost as the original dot for that level of the Arcanos.

The section on spending XP gives the following costs related to arcanoi:

| Trait | XP Cost |
| --- | --- |
| New Arcanos | 7 |
| Arcanos | current rating * 3 |
| … | … |

From the first paragraph, the "current rating" when there's existing art is *not* the rating of the arcanos that's written on the character sheet, but the what the rating would have been when first increasing the rating to the art being learned; in other words, 1 less than the rating to be learned.

This seems to leave out one case. What's the XP cost for learning a 1 dot art for a known arcanoi (ignoring any discounts for a guild tutor)?

For example, suppose a wraith had two dots in Argos, both in the initiate arts (Enshroud, Wayfarer's Resolve), and the player wanted the character to learn the 1-dot common art (Weather Eye). It's not a new arcanos, so it shouldn't be the 7 cost. Additionally, having a 1-dot art cost more than a 2 dot art (Phantom Wings would cost 3) doesn't seem reasonable. The only other rule would put the cost at 0 xp (the "current rating", which would be 0 for a 1-dot art, times 3), which also isn't reasonable.

Comment: "The first dot is more expensive" is a common hallmark of White Wolf games. E.g. in Vampire, the first dot of a clan Discipline costs 10xp, and the second dot costs five. The first dot of a new ability is 3xp, the second 2.

Comment: @AceCalhoon: those cases are the first dot in something new, which is covered by the 7-point cost for a new arcanoi. In this case, it's not really the first dot, but a lower-level dot in something already possessed. In Vampire, it's most similar to the 20th Anniv. edition where you can buy alternate applications for 6+ ratings at the same cost as the first time obtaining that same rating.

Answer (score 3):

There might not be a definitive answer in the 20th Anniversary rules, but a look at the 2nd edition suggests two options. There, XP costs for arcanoi are the same as in the 20th, but it also has a cost of 4 points for basic arcanoi (which are basically 0-point arts) and thus a cost of 3 XP to get the first dot when the basic arts are known (this is explicitly noted at the bottom of the XP cost chart on p. 228). This 3-point cost could be taken for the 20th Anniversary edition as the cost for 1-dot arts in a known arcanoi. This makes the cost for 1- and 2-dot arts the same, which may not seem entirely balanced, but has precedence (this is also the case in 2nd edition). Additionally, it's relatively cheap, especially with a discount for Guild instruction.

More to the point, the section on Arcanoi in the 2nd edition (p. 133) has near the start an aside on learning "alternate arts", including a table of XP costs. The cost to learn an alternate level 1 art (when the wraith has at least 1 level in the arcanoi) is 1 point. The costs for higher level alternate arts are the same as for learning that level the first time (just as it is in 20th).